# Why doesn't clang allow accessing a nested enum class through an instance?

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct S {
    enum class EnumClass {
        one
    } ;

    enum Enum {
        one
    };
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    S::EnumClass e = s.EnumClass::one; // <- Doesn't compile with clang
    S::Enum e11 = s.Enum::one;
    S::Enum e12 = s.one;
}
```

Everything works with GCC, but clang (neither 3.8 nor 3.9) does not compile `s.EnumClass::one`, giving an error: `'S::EnumClass::one' is not a member of class 'S'`.

Given the fact that unscoped enums work fine, it seems like a bug.

Comment: Interesting... Visual Studio will happily compile this without warning, but intellisense highlights the same error as Clang. Coincidence?

Comment: "[*the id-expression shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes.*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2.sentence-5)" seems relevant.

Comment: @Rakete1111 But maybe enum values can be considered members (kind of static?) of the enclosing class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat See [class.member]p1 and p3. They are considered members of the class, as weird as it sounds.

Comment: How should one access nested (enum) class members, then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in gcc<sup>1</sup>. The relevant wording is in [[expr.ref]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2):

> In either case, the *id-expression* [here: `EnumClass::one`] shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes.

`EnumClass::one` does not refer to a member of a class, it's a member of an enum. It doesn't matter whether that enum is part of the class, it's just that the member `one` itself is not part of the class.

But is `Enum::one` part of the class? Yes, according to [[class.member]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-1):

> Members of a class are data members, member functions, nested types, enumerators, and member templates and specializations thereof.

and made more explicit in [[class.member]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-3):

> The enumerators of an unscoped enumeration defined in the class are members of the class.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I would even go as far as to call it a bug in the standard, as there doesn't seem to be any (technical) reason why this should be disallowed and I think it would be a good idea to allow it. There are talks about allowing it though, so let's see what the committee decides.

Comment: Regarding what is and isn't a member, it seems like it's the same as `struct S { struct T { static const int t = 0; }; } s; int main() { return s.T::t; }` which is rejected by gcc, clang, Intel and MSVC alike. If that isn't accepted, I don't see why the `enum` equivalent should be any different, so I'm having trouble seeing it as a bug in the standard, rather than just a bug in gcc (and MSVC).

Comment: @hvd And what I'm saying is that that too should be changed, as it doesn't make any sense IMO. :)

Comment: The syntax `s.T::t` already has a well-established meaning, which is to access members from a base class even if they may have been hidden by a derived class. I suppose it's possible to make an exception that `.`'s LHS expression doesn't need to be derived from the declaring type if it wouldn't actually be used, but that would allow a lot of undesirable stuff too, and break existing code relying on SFINAE.

Comment: [expr.ref#4.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#4.4) also says that an expression E1.E2 is ill-formed, unless (expr.ref#4.4) E2 is a member enumerator. [dcl.enum#11](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#11) says that scoped enumerator has the scope of its enum, and only an enumerator declared in class scope (that is, an unscoped enum) can be referred to using the class member access operators.

Comment: @Rakete1111: +1 if you would be so kind to explaing how one should access nested (enum) class members, then?

Comment: @Florian well naming the class always works: `S::EnumClass::one` or `decltype(s)::EnumClass::one`.

Comment: @Rakete1111: For template classes the former is going to be a mess, the latter one works - yet this seems overly cumbersome to me... (and similar to a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874432/abbreviate-argument-to-member-function-expecting-introduced-type-enum-class/54886510#54886510) I asked.)